# delegate in a non existing element

Tags: jquery, delegates

What happens if I do this:

```
$('#elementID').delegate('.findclick a', 'click', function()
{
   alert("test");
}
```

And firstly:

`#elementID` doesn't exist in the document

or

`#elementID` exists BUT `.findclick a` doesn't exist.

Is it really bad? Or it doesn't matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't trigger... so it doesn't matter.

If you dynamically add these element (using `.on()`) it will trigger and work then.

---

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delegatedElementThatDoNotExistYet', function() {
    alert("Welcome");
});
```

nothing happen because the delegated element doesn't exist, but:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('body').html('<a class="delegatedElementThatDoNotExistYet">Hello!</a>');
},5000);
```

if after few seconds (5 in my example) we add the element delegated it will fire the alert.

Here the example on **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/9Syqh/)**

Answer (score 0):

- First case isn't really bad since you wouldn't attach listener to a
  none existing node.
- Second might become bad if at some point you have `.findclick a`
  children of `#elementID` then  your.

```
function(){
   alert("test");
}
```

will trigger every time you click these anchors.

The point is you bind the listener to the parent and it takes care of the children

Answer (score 0):

If `#elementID` doesn't exist then nothing happens at all; the element isn't there so an event handler can't be bound to it.

If `#elementID` does exist, then congratulations, you've just set up [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Simply put, event delegation is the technique by which you set up event handlers on elements that don't exist yet, but will at some point after the page loads.

That second situation is precisely how `.delegate()` is **intended** to be used.

Answer (score 0):

> `#elementID` doesn't exist in the document

It creates a function, which is then applied to the result set as a delegate (which is empty); so nothing happens (the created function will get garbage collected eventually).

> `#elementID` exists BUT `.findclick a` doesn't exist.

Again, it creates a function, which is then applied to the result set as a delegate (which should contain exactly *one* element).

Now, whenever `#elementID` or any element inside of it is clicked, jQuery will iterate over the registered delegates (there should be only one) to find a matching selector (`'.findclick a'`).

When you later create `.findclick a` underneath `#elementID` it will start to run your function when it's clicked upon.